# Finding the gradient in least squares

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, optimization, vectors, nonlinear-optimization

In Linear squares optimization I have
A=\begin{pmatrix}
     1 & t_1 & t_1^2 & \cdots & t_1^k \\
     1 & t_2 & t_2^2 & \cdots & t_2^k \\
     \vdots  & \vdots& \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
     1 & t_n & t_n^2 & \cdots & t_n^k    
     \end{pmatrix}
and X=\begin{pmatrix}
        x_0 \\
        x_1  \\
        \vdots\\
x_n\\
        \end{pmatrix}

I want to find the gradient of $(AX)^TAX$.

Since $(AX)^TAX$ results in a scaler I let an element of $AX$ be $V_i$ and so $(AX)^TAX=\sum_{i=1}^{n}V_i^2$.   where $V_i=\sum_{j=1}^{k+1}a_{ij}X_j$.

So ${\partial ((AX)^TAX)\over \partial X_j}=\sum_{i=1}^n2V_i{\partial V_i\over \partial X_j}=2\sum_{i=1}^n(\sum_{j=1}^{k+1}a_{ij}X_j)a_{ij}=2\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^{k+1}a_{ij}^2X_j$.

But I think this is wrong as I want gradient $(AX)^TAX=2A^TAX$.
Can some one please tell  me whether my approach is wrong and what I should do

Comment: The gradient of $f(x) = x^T M x$ is $\nabla f(x) = (M+M^T)x$. In your case notice that $(AX)^TAX = X^T(A^TA)X$ and $A^TA + (A^TA)^T = 2A^TA$ since $A^TA$ is symmetric.

Comment: @AndreasT Thanks for the reply. Can you please explain how $\nabla f(x) = (M+M^T)x$ happens? I know how to take gradient. But when it is in matrix notation like this it is confusing.

Comment: I expanded the comment into a more detailed answer. I hope that makes it more clear

Comment: is it clear now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**(Expanding a comment)**

More generally, you can observe that for any matrix $M\in\mathbb R^{n\times n}$, the function
$$
\begin{array}{rrcl}
f: &\hspace{-5pt}\mathbb R^n &\hspace{-5pt} \longrightarrow &\hspace{-5pt} \mathbb R \\
   &\hspace{-5pt} x &\hspace{-5pt} \longmapsto &\hspace{-5pt} x^TMx 
\end{array}
$$
is differentiable and has gradient
$$\tag{1}
\nabla f(x) = (M+M^T)x
$$
Once you verify this, your claim immediately follows in that $(AX)^T(AX) = X^T(A^TA)X$ and $A^TA$ is symmetric and hence $(A^TA)^T+(A^TA)=2A^TA$.

We are left to verify the general statement $(1)$.
$$
f(x) = x^TMx = \sum_{i,j=1}^n M_{i,j}x_ix_j
$$
hence for $\alpha=1\ldots n$, the $\alpha$-th component of the gradient is
$$
\bigl(\nabla f(x)\bigr)_\alpha
=
\frac{\partial}{\partial x_\alpha}\sum_{i,j=1}^n M_{i,j}x_ix_j
=
\sum_{i,j=1}^n M_{i,j}\tfrac{\partial}{\partial x_\alpha}(x_ix_j)
=
\sum_{i,j=1}^n M_{i,j}
\left(
 \tfrac{\partial}{\partial x_\alpha}(x_i) x_j
 +
 x_i\tfrac{\partial}{\partial x_\alpha}(x_j)
\right)
$$
Now, since $\tfrac{\partial}{\partial x_\alpha}(x_i) = 1$ if $\alpha=i$ and $0$ otherwise, dividing the sum into two sums, the sums reduce to
$$
\bigl(\nabla f(x)\bigr)_\alpha
=
\underbrace{
 \sum_{j=1}^n M_{\alpha,j}
  x_j
}_{i=\alpha}
+
\underbrace{
 \sum_{i=1}^n M_{i,\alpha}
  x_i
}_{j=\alpha}
\stackrel{\text{renaming indices}}{=}
\sum_{\beta=1}^n
 \left(
  M_{\alpha,\beta} + M_{\beta,\alpha}
 \right)
 x_\beta
=
 \bigl(
  Mx+M^Tx
 \bigr)_\alpha
=
 \bigl(
  (M+M^T)x
 \bigr)_\alpha
$$
(The subscript $\alpha$ still refers to the $\alpha$-th element of the vector). This proves the claim.

**A faster way to see all this** is using the bilinearity of the scalar product $x^TMx = \langle x, Mx\rangle$ and taking the gradient of the last expression.